# Scroll to right in Tradingview chart using python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, click

I am trying to scroll right using selenium python in [TradingView](https://tradingview.com/chart/)

[image]

My Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='control-bar__btn control-bar__btn--move-right apply-common-tooltip']").click()
```

It throws an error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
> element not  interactable

Comment: Can you share HTML in text format or where we have to navigate to find _scroll to right ot left_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code -

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.tradingview.com/chart/')

try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class,\"closeIcon\")]"))).click()
except:
    pass

RightScroll = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,\"btn--move-right\")]")))

for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(2)
    print(i)
    action.move_to_element(RightScroll).click().perform()
```

If it solves your problem then please mark it as answer. Do let me know if you have any query.

Comment: for loops is just to click 10 times?

Comment: Yes, I have used that code to show you that we can scroll to the right. If you would like to scroll more you can increase the number. If it resolves your problem then please mark it as answer. This will be more encouraging.

Comment: yup, this really helped me out, just wanted to know any solution without using actionchains?

Answer (score 0):

There is a message window displayed when you first load the page. You have to close it first (to get the right arrow container visible) if you are not doing it by

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'closeIcon')]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@class='chart-markup-table time-axis']")).click();//To get the right arrow container visible

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='control-bar__btn control-bar__btn--move-right apply-common-tooltip']")).click();

Comment: this is not python